# How to manipulate List arrays?

Tags: flutter, dart, arraylist

I've created a two dimensional List using List.generate and then I want to iterate through the List and change the first value in each row. I've done this in Dartpad and it works as expected. I can't get it to work in my Flutter app.

Here's the code that works in Dartpad:

List myList =
List.generate (12, (I) => List<String>.filled (12, '-'), growable: false);

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  int s = i + 1;
  myList[i][0] = "List $s";
}
```

But when I use it in Flutter as follows:

```
class _MyPage extends State<MyPage> {
  
  List myList =
      List.generate(12, (i) => List<String>.filled(12, '-'), growable: false);
  
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
      int s = i + 1;
      myList[i][0] = "List $s";
    }
```

Flutter errors on the **for **loop stating:

Expected a class member.
Try placing this code inside a class member.

Removing the for loop leave the initial generated list, myList filled with '-' but I want to change the first item in each row to 'List x' by using a for loop.

Comment: This is a part where you declare members of class `_MyPage`. You need to put your code within methods, not the class declaration. `void myFunction() { for... }`

Comment: can you include full sample widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare in a `class` only members that belong to it like variables, methods, getters...

adding directly a `for` loop is wrong and can't be accepted, however, in the other hand you can declare a `function` that executes the `for` loop code, like this:

```
class _MyPage extends State<MyPage> {

List myList =
  List.generate(12, (i) => List<String>.filled(12, '-'), growable: false);

executeLoop() {
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  int s = i + 1;
  myList[i][0] = "List $s";
}
}
```

now we have a class member which is the `executeLoop`, and now you can call that function to execute it.

the `StateFulWidget` have a lifecycle method called `initState()`, which is called automatically when the widget is added to the tree widget, so you can do like this:

```
  class _MyPage extends State<MyPage> {
List myList =List.generate(12, (i) => List<String>.filled(12, '-'), growable: false);
  


executeLoop() {
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
  int s = i + 1;
  myList[i][0] = "List $s";
}

@override
 initState() {
 super.initState();
 executeLoop();
}
}
```

and now the `executeLoop` will be executed, which means that your `for` loop will be executed now as you expect.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you Gwhyy, worked perfectly. I haven't done any code for years, when I did a bit of Visual Basic, so on a steep learning curve now. Thanks again for your help.